# Why does the "next badges" progress display sometimes appears in the "recent achievements" dropdown and sometimes not?

Tags: discussion, badges, recent-activity

That says it all.

Also, when I first noticed it, I asked about it on chat, and someone said something like "Apparently, it's had been there a while, but I just noticed it."

Is it intermittently displayed and what determines it?

Comment: You mean like this question on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev)? If so, it's something that SE is doing AB testing on, so it may appear for you on some computers/browsers but not on others.

Comment: FWIW, I see it on my phone, but not my computer's browser.

Comment: @Catija:   Yes, that seems to be the answer

Comment: @Catija: Maybe I'm dumb but that other meta mentions that you can get the same information a different way "with one click".   That way is not obvious to me at all.  How do you get badge progress??

Comment: That's complicated on SF because you guys don't have the new user pages yet... so you don't actually have progress bars. There's about a dozen sites with really old site designs that don't allow for the new user pages. It's discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) on Meta.SE. For an example of the new User pages, see my page on [M&TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420/catija).

Comment: @Catija:   Thanks.  So where's progress?

Comment: @Catija:  OK -- I [see](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420/catija?tab=badges)

Answer (score 2):

They were A/B testing it as a new feature. Anna Lear [commented on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev#comment862723_265859) on September 6th:

> We're A/B-testing this tracker right now. Assuming it performs well, we'll put more time into "congrats! you earned X" notifications. (Our initial designs for it interfered with how we decide when to mark achievements as "read" and we opted to run the test without making any changes to that first.)

You won't be seeing it again for a while, though (if at all). Thomas Orozco, one of SE's Product Managers, [commented yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev#comment865602_265841):

> The A/B test has completed for now, but we'll probably run another one before making a final decision (for a variety of reasons that don't really make sense to explain here). Either way, if we were to decide to move forward with it (that decision has **not** been made yet), we'd work towards making it less intrusive. So, for the time being, I'll make this status-review.